# Real Time Notification on every processes in Node Js & Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io

I want to show real time push notification to every user if someone started any kind off process. My project is in Angular and Node JS. If any user start some process then every user in the site should be notified by push notification

Comment: you can use Firebase Cloud Messaging or websocket to make a flow of real time notification

Comment: @rahultiwari I need more information of how to start with any useful documentation.

Comment: https://medium.com/mighty-ghost-hack/angular-8-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-cc80d9b36f82

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your server side, you would need a socket solution to enable real time notification.

Since you are using NodeJs as your backend, you can try out `socket.io`. I personally find them quite easy to use. Their documentation can be found via their site.

https://socket.io/

If you need a step by step guide on how to combine nodeJS + socket.io + Angular, you can refer to this guide by DigitalOcean

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-socket-io

On the angular side, you need to develop a way to ensure the notification is consumed by all users. Two simple methods about this could

1. either be done via your state management like NGRX,
2. or via a global service